# Can't Install FFMPEG with homebrew

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I tried installing FFmpeg with homebrew today. When I enter "brew install FFmpeg" I get this:

[image: (my terminal)]

I tried running commands like `brew doctor` and `git -C $(--repo homebrew/core)`

I'm using macOS Big Sur btw.

EDIT: I installed FFmpeg as a final solution it seems to be working now. Thanks for helping, guys. I don't know what's wrong with my homebrew though.

Comment: What happens if you try a `brew install nasm` ?

Comment: Try running `brew tap` to see if you have any taps you shouldn't have. Then use `brew untap XYZ` to remove any unwanted taps,

Comment: Lazy solution is to [download an already compiled `ffmpeg`](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/) and put it in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: @llgon that's what I did and it seems to be working now. I still don't know what's wrong with the homebrew though. Anyway, thanks, man.

Answer (score 1):

It's a weird error, but a workaround would be to execute following commands:

```sh
$~ wget https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/stable/nasm-2.15.05.zip -O nasm.zip
$~ unzip nasm.zip
$~ cd nasm*
$~/nasm ./configure --prefix /usr
$~/nasm make
$~/nasm sudo make install
```

The above

1. downloads the zipped source code
2. unzips it
3. goes into the unzipped folder
4. configures the source code to have the programs installed to the right place
5. builds programs and libraries from the source code
6. installs everything that has been built

After that, your homebrew should find `nasm` and just skip it.

#### EDIT:

Whilst the above should work perfectly fine on Linux, I learned that it does *not* work on Mac OS (thank you @Philippe !) as stated in the Mac OS docs on [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899):

> System Integrity Protection includes protection for these parts of the system:
>
> - /System
> - /usr
> - /bin
> - /sbin
> - /var
> - Apps that are pre-installed with OS X
>   Paths and apps that third-party apps and installers can continue to write to include:
> - /Applications
> - /Library
> - /usr/local

So, we can conclude that we cannot install `nasm` into `/usr`, but into `/usr/local`. That means command No. 4 should be changed to `./configure --prefix /usr/local`.

EDIT2:
In case you get an error in step 1, use `curl https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/stable/nasm-2.15.05.zip -o nasm.zip` instead.
In case you get an error about your shell not finding `/bin/sh`, prepend the name of a shell you have installed on your PC to the command line.

Comment: Can you install into `/usr` without being `root` ?

Comment: @Philippe of course you can't, you need to put sudo before the install command, I wonder why I didn't think of that …

Comment: With recent MacOS like Catalina, or Big Sur, you cannot install into /usr, even with root. Have you tried your commands ?

Comment: @Philippe I can't try them 'cause I don't have a Mac ! :@ but I as Mac OS is similar to Linux, I thought one could just use the same commands as on Linux …

Comment: @Philippe I did a bit of research and edited my post, it should work now.

Comment: I already have ffmpeg installed, and I dont remeber I had this problem, Let's wait for OP to confirm.

Comment: @Philippe UMMM … I didn't notice you were not the OP !!!

Comment: So I can't install wget right now. Gives the same error every time and doesn't let me install anything.

Comment: @dcnaber does that mean you are getting the same error about nasm when trying to install wget ?

Comment: @dcnaber do you have curl installed ? If so, instead of the wget command run `curl https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/stable/nasm-2.15.05.zip -o nasm.zip`

Comment: @Programmer Alright I guess it installed nasm now right? Here is what I got [my terminal](https://i.hizliresim.com/tv7d4b.png)

Comment: @dcnaber it only downloaded the nasm source code; gratulations for completing step 1 ! Now you have to proceed with the remaining 5 steps in order to build and install nasm.

Comment: @Programmer I tried both `./configure --prefix /usr` and `./configure --prefix /usr/local` neither seemed to worked and I got this as a result: [my terminal](https://i.hizliresim.com/lmelsm.png). Tried to google and see the solutions but couldn't find any.

Comment: @dcnaber wow, you seem to have a setup completely different than mine … `zsh configure --prefix /usr/local` should work !

Comment: @Programmer yeah, I had to install it manually and it's working. I don't know what's wrong with my homebrew though.